# planning_environment_msgs in electric

Tags: ros, planning-environment, arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The planning_environment page, regarding electric, states, "A number of changes have been made to the planning_environment. Details to follow, but much of the information on diamondback no longer holds."

Where are planning_environment_msgs now kept? Particularly, what replaced the message and service, get_joints_in_group (planning_environment_msgs/GetJointsInGroup)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12522/planning_environment_msgs-in-electric/) by [seanarm](https://answers.ros.org/users/443/seanarm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 753 on 2012-01-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This service was removed for performance reasons - you can this information (and a whole bunch of other useful functions) from the C++ planning_environment interface using this code:

```
#include <planning_environment/models/collision_models.h>

      planning_environment::CollisionModels collision_models("robot_description");
      std::vector<std::string> joint_names = collision_models->getKinematicModel()->getModelGroup(GROUP_NAME)->getJointModelNames();
```

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2012-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3